# Compiler not enforcing return contract

Tags: c++

for the following code

```
int foo(int a = 10, int b = 20);

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a + b;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

I don't get a compiler error. Instead, I get this

> Error(s):
>   Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)
>   3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303

Any idea why the compiler simply does not error out saying you forget to return an int as promised in the function prototype?

This is on clang

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g` ...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: code should not compile, as you haven't provided a declaration for `cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's impossible to determine this in the general case, the standard leaves it undefined.
(If memory serves, it would involve solving *the halting problem*, which you can prove is impossible.)

The best you can do is to increase your warning level and treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea why the compiler simply does not error out saying you forget to return an int as promised in the function prototype?

Primarily, because it is not required to. Standard says that not returning from a non-void function has undefined behaviour.

And, because presumably the author(s) of the compiler decided that a warning is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not output an error because it does not have to. The standard says it should be undefined behavior, so no diagnostics required.

However, you might want to enable warnings, and maybe even treat that warning as an error.

In GCC, it's done by adding this argument:

```
-Werror=return-type
```